# how to make redirect to a specific url?

Tags: redirect, themes, opencart, journal

I am running opecart 3 with the new journal theme 3. 
The product page has a "quick buy" button that automatically adds product details to the cart and then redirects the customer to the checkout page.

I cannot seem to change the url for the quick_buy button. I need it to do what it does as above, but to instead redirect the user to a custom url..

How can I achieve this?

Code as seen here:

```js
// Array includes polyfill
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
        value: function (searchElement, fromIndex) {

            if (this == null) {
                throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
            }

            // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
            var o = Object(this);

            // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
            var len = o.length >>> 0;

            // 3. If len is 0, return false.
            if (len === 0) {
                return false;
            }

            // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
            //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
            var n = fromIndex | 0;

            // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
            //  a. Let k be n.
            // 6. Else n < 0,
            //  a. Let k be len + n.
            //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
            var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);

            function sameValueZero(x, y) {
                return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
            }

            // 7. Repeat, while k < len
            while (k < len) {
                // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
                // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
                if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
                    return true;
                }
                // c. Increase k by 1.
                k++;
            }

            // 8. Return false
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    // Currency
    $('#form-currency .currency-select').unbind().on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#form-currency input[name=\'code\']').val($(this).data('name'));

        $('#form-currency').submit();
    });

    // Language
    $('#form-language .language-select').unbind().on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#form-language input[name=\'code\']').val($(this).data('name'));

        $('#form-language').submit();
    });
});

window['cart'].add = function (product_id, quantity, quick_buy) {
    quantity = quantity || 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
            $('[onclick*="cart.add(\'' + product_id + '\'"]').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('[onclick*="cart.add(\'' + product_id + '\'"]').button('reset');
        },
        success: function (json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                if (json['options_popup']) {
                    if ($('html').hasClass('iphone') || $('html').hasClass('ipad')) {
                        iNoBounce.enable();
                    }

                    var html = '';

                    html += '<div class="popup-wrapper popup-options">';
                    html += '    <div class="popup-container">';
                    html += '        <button class="btn popup-close"></button>';
                    html += '        <div class="popup-body">';
                    html += '        <div class="popup-inner-body">';
                    html += '            <div class="journal-loading"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
                    html += '            <iframe src="index.php?route=journal3/product&product_id=' + product_id + '&popup=options&product_quantity=' + quantity + '&' + (quick_buy ? 'quick_buy=true' : '') + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" onload="this.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight; $(this).prev(\'.journal-loading\').fadeOut();"></iframe>';
                    html += '        </div>';
                    html += '        </div>';
                    html += '    </div>';
                    html += '    <div class="popup-bg popup-bg-closable"></div>';
                    html += '</div>';

                    // show modal
                    $('.popup-wrapper').remove();

                    $('body').append(html);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('html').addClass('popup-open popup-center');
                    }, 10);
                } else {
                    location = json['redirect'];
                }
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                if (json['options_popup']) {
                    if ($('html').hasClass('iphone') || $('html').hasClass('ipad')) {
                        iNoBounce.enable();
                    }

                    var html = '';

                    html += '<div class="popup-wrapper popup-options">';
                    html += '    <div class="popup-container">';
                    html += '        <button class="btn popup-close"></button>';
                    html += '        <div class="popup-body">';
                    html += '        <div class="popup-inner-body">';
                    html += '            <div class="journal-loading"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
                    html += '            <iframe src="index.php?route=journal3/product&product_id=' + product_id + '&popup=options&' + (quick_buy ? 'quick_buy=true' : '') + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" onload="this.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight; $(this).prev(\'.journal-loading\').fadeOut();"></iframe>';
                    html += '        </div>';
                    html += '        </div>';
                    html += '    </div>';
                    html += '    <div class="popup-bg popup-bg-closable"></div>';
                    html += '</div>';

                    // show modal
                    $('.popup-wrapper').remove();

                    $('body').append(html);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('html').addClass('popup-open popup-center');
                    }, 10);
                } else {
                    if (json['notification']) {
                        show_notification(json['notification']);

                        if (quick_buy) {
                            location = 'index.php?route=checkout/checkout';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('header').after('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                    }
                }

                // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                    $('#cart-items').html(json['items_count']);
                }, 100);

                if (Journal['scrollToTop']) {
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                }

                $('.cart-content ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');

                if (parent.window['_QuickCheckout']) {
                    parent.window['_QuickCheckout'].save();
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + '\r\n' + xhr.statusText + '\r\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};

window['cart'].remove = function (key) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'key=' + key,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#cart > button').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#cart > button').button('reset');
        },
        success: function (json) {
            // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                $('#cart-items').html(json['items_count']);
            }, 100);

            if ($('html').hasClass('route-checkout-cart') || $('html').hasClass('route-checkout-checkout')) {
                location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            } else {
                $('.cart-content ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + '\r\n' + xhr.statusText + '\r\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};

window['cart'].update = function (key, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#cart > button').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#cart > button').button('reset');
        },
        success: function (json) {
            // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                $('#cart-items').html(json['items_count']);
            }, 100);

            if ($('html').hasClass('route-checkout-cart') || $('html').hasClass('route-checkout-checkout')) {
                location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
            } else {
                $('.cart-content ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + '\r\n' + xhr.statusText + '\r\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};

window['wishlist'].add = function (product_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=account/wishlist/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            $('.alert').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');

                if (json['notification']) {
                    show_notification(json['notification']);
                } else {
                    $('header').after('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                }
            }

            $('#wishlist-total span').html(json['total']);
            $('#wishlist-total').attr('title', json['total']);
            $('.wishlist-badge').text(json['count']);

            if (Journal['scrollToTop']) {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + '\r\n' + xhr.statusText + '\r\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};

window['compare'].add = function (product_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/compare/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            $('.alert').remove();

            if (json['success']) {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');

                if (json['notification']) {
                    show_notification(json['notification']);
                } else {
                    $('header').after('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                }

                $('#compare-total').html(json['total']);
                $('.compare-badge').text(json['count']);

                if (Journal['scrollToTop']) {
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + '\r\n' + xhr.statusText + '\r\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};

window['quickview'] = function (product_id) {
    product_id = parseInt(product_id, 10);

    // hide tooltip
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');

    var html = '';

    html += '<div class="popup-wrapper popup-quickview">';
    html += '    <div class="popup-container">';
    html += '        <button class="btn popup-close"></button>';
    html += '        <div class="popup-body">';
    html += '            <div class="popup-inner-body">';
    html += '                <div class="journal-loading"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
    html += '                <iframe src="index.php?route=journal3/product&product_id=' + product_id + '&popup=quickview" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" onload="this.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight; $(this).prev(\'.journal-loading\').hide();"></iframe>';
    html += '            </div>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '    </div>';
    html += '    <div class="popup-bg popup-bg-closable"></div>';
    html += '</div>';

    // show modal
    $('.popup-wrapper').remove();

    $('body').append(html);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('html').addClass('popup-open popup-center');
    }, 10);
};

window['open_popup'] = function (module_id) {
    if ($('html').hasClass('iphone') || $('html').hasClass('ipad')) {
        iNoBounce.enable();
    }

    module_id = parseInt(module_id, 10);

    var html = '';

    html += '<div class="popup-wrapper popup-module">';
    html += '    <div class="popup-container">';
    html += '        <button class="btn popup-close"></button>';
    html += '        <div class="popup-body">';
    html += '        <div class="popup-inner-body">';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '    </div>';
    html += '    <div class="popup-bg popup-bg-closable"></div>';
    html += '</div>';

    // show modal
    $('.popup-wrapper').remove();

    $('body').append(html);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('html').addClass('popup-open popup-center');
    }, 10);

    $('.popup-container').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=journal3/popup/get&module_id=' + module_id + '&popup=module',
        success: function (html) {
            var $html = $(html);
            var $popup = $html.siblings('.module-popup');
            var $style = $html.siblings('style');
            var $content = $popup.find('.popup-container');

            $('#popup-style-' + module_id).remove();
            $('head').append($style.attr('id', 'popup-style-' + module_id));
            $('.popup-wrapper').attr('class', $popup.attr('class'));
            $('.popup-container').html($content.html());

            $('.popup-container').css('visibility', 'visible');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + '\r\n' + xhr.statusText + '\r\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};

window['open_login_popup'] = function () {
    if ($('html').hasClass('iphone') || $('html').hasClass('ipad')) {
        iNoBounce.enable();
    }

    var html = '';

    html += '<div class="popup-wrapper popup-login">';
    html += '    <div class="popup-container">';
    html += '        <button class="btn popup-close"></button>';
    html += '        <div class="popup-body">';
    html += '        <div class="popup-inner-body">';
    html += '            <div class="journal-loading"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
    html += '            <iframe src="index.php?route=account/login&popup=login" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" onload="this.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight; $(this).prev(\'.journal-loading\').fadeOut();"></iframe>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '    </div>';
    html += '    <div class="popup-bg popup-bg-closable"></div>';
    html += '</div>';

    // show modal
    $('.popup-wrapper').remove();

    $('body').append(html);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('html').addClass('popup-open popup-center');
    }, 10);
};

window['open_register_popup'] = function () {
    if ($('html').hasClass('iphone') || $('html').hasClass('ipad')) {
        iNoBounce.enable();
    }

    var html = '';

    html += '<div class="popup-wrapper popup-register">';
    html += '    <div class="popup-container">';
    html += '        <button class="btn popup-close"></button>';
    html += '        <div class="popup-body">';
    html += '        <div class="popup-inner-body">';
    html += '            <div class="journal-loading"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';
    html += '            <iframe src="index.php?route=account/register&popup=register" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" onload="this.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight; $(this).prev(\'.journal-loading\').fadeOut();"></iframe>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '    </div>';
    html += '    <div class="popup-bg popup-bg-closable"></div>';
    html += '</div>';

    // show modal
    $('.popup-wrapper').remove();

    $('body').append(html);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('html').addClass('popup-open popup-center');
    }, 10);
};

window['show_notification'] = function (opts) {
    opts = $.extend({
        position: 'center',
        className: '',
        title: '',
        image: '',
        message: '',
        buttons: [],
        timeout: Journal.notificationHideAfter
    }, opts);

    if ($('.notification-wrapper-' + opts.position).length === 0) {
        $('body').append('<div class="notification-wrapper notification-wrapper-' + opts.position + '"></div>');
    }

    var html = '';

    var buttons = $.map(opts.buttons, function (button) {
        return '<a class="' + button.className + '" href="' + button.href + '">' + button.name + '</a>';
    });

    html += '<div class="notification ' + opts.className + '">';
    html += '    <button class="btn notification-close"></button>';
    html += '    <div class="notification-content">';

    if (opts.image) {
        html += '        <img src="' + opts.image + '" srcset="' + opts.image + ' 1x, ' + opts.image2x + ' 2x">';
    }

    html += '        <div>';
    html += '            <div class="notification-title">' + opts.title + '</div>';
    html += '            <div class="notification-text">' + opts.message + '</div>';
    html += '        </div>';
    html += '    </div>';

    if (buttons && buttons.length) {
        html += '<div class="notification-buttons">' + buttons.join('\n') + '</div>';
    }

    html += '</div>';

    var $notification = $(html);

    $('.notification-wrapper-' + opts.position).append($notification);

    if (opts.timeout) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $notification.find('.notification-close').trigger('click');
        }, opts.timeout);
    }

    return $notification;
};

window['loader'] = function (el, status) {
    var $el = $(el);

    if (status) {
        $el.attr('style', 'position: relative');
        $el.append('<div class="journal-loading-overlay"><div class="journal-loading"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div></div>');
    } else {
        $el.attr('style', '');
        $el.find('.journal-loading-overlay').remove();
    }
};

window['resize_iframe'] = function (module_id, height) {
    $('.module-popup-' + module_id + ' iframe').height(height);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is helpful to share what you have tried already so that folks don't suggest the same things you have already tried, plus it shows that you have tried to solve the problem and aren't just looking for someone to do the work for you.

Comment: i have tried to adjust the link for

if (quick_buy) {
       location = 'index.php?route=checkout/checkout';
      }

but doesnt seem to do anything on the front end. have cleared cache and modifications refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code provided I can see that there is only one method that is really redirecting, and that is `window['cart'].add`

obviously, this code is responsible for redirecting

`location = 'index.php?route=checkout/checkout';`

yet, the `location` is not used anywhere after that. So it is a dead end.

Journal is one of the most mysterious frameworks I know, so it is no surprise for me. Here are something I would do.

1. edit this `location` parameter to the custom link like so `location = 'index.php?route=product/special';`
2. clear the twig cache so that we are sure the changes take place
3. if that doesn't work, check the controller file of `catalog/controller/checkout/cart` in method `add` and see if there is any custom redirect.
4. remember to check the modification files in `system/storage/modification/...` for the `controller/checkout/cart.php` and the twig `view/theme/.../...twig`

I hope I managed to push you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for the help!! i found the culprit in the

/catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/product/product.twig


        if ($btn.data('quick-buy') !== undefined) {
          location = 'this-location-here';
        }

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help!! i found the culprit in the

/catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/product/product.twig

```
    if ($btn.data('quick-buy') !== undefined) {
      location = 'this-location-here';
    }
```